# Toggle multiple images on multiple buttons\Divs inside main div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that toggle images inside div. My problem is when i try to toggle images in div-1 everything is ok but when im starting toggle images in div 2, images from div 1 dissapear and opposite way asswell. Please help. Im new in coding jquery. The website that im building have a lot. The website that im building have a lot more categories and i need to toggle images in all of them.

```
<html>    
<body>
    <div id="Image-Holder-bg" class="inner ">
        <img class="animal1" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/3/3a/100px-DJ.png/revision/latest?cb=20140813091425&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        <img class="animal2" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/7/7e/100px-Owen.png/revision/latest?cb=20140813152315&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        <img class="animal3" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/4/48/100px-Bridgette.png/revision/latest?cb=20140813090348&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        <img class="animal4" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/d/df/100px-Staci.png/revision/latest?cb=20140813153602&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
    </div>

    <div id="Cat" target=".animal1" class="carouselanimal">animal1</div>
    <div id="Dog" target=".animal2" class="carouselanimal">animal2</div>
    <div id="Zebra" target=".animal3" class="carouselanimal">animal3</div>
    <div id="Peacock" target=".animal4" class="carouselanimal">animal4</div>

    <div id="Image-Holder-fg" class="inner ">
        <img class="popart1" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/3/38/100px-Leonard_ID.png/revision/latest?cb=20160304145758&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        <img class="popart2" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/0/00/100px-Duncan.png/revision/latest?cb=20140813123905&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        <img class="popart3" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/e/e1/100px-TDA_DIY_Char_Beth.png/revision/latest?cb=20140812140203&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        <img class="popart4" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/totalna-porazka/images/3/3e/100px-Izzy.png/revision/latest?cb=20140812135527&path-prefix=pl" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
    </div>

    <div id="art1" target=".popart1" class="carouselpopart">popart1</div>
    <div id="art2" target=".popart2" class="carouselpopart">popart2</div>
    <div id="art3" target=".popart3" class="carouselpopart">popart3</div>
    <div id="art4" target=".popart4" class="carouselpopart">popart4</div>
</body>    
</html>

<style>
    .carouselanimal {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        Height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    .carouselpopart {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        Height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    #Image-Holder-bg {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: solid 2px red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #Image-Holder-fg {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: solid 2px red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $('.carouselanimal').click(function(a) {
        var $target = $($(this).attr("target"));
        $('img').hide();
        $target.show();
    });

    $('.carouselpopart').click(function(b) {
        var $target = $($(this).attr("target"));
        $('img').hide();
        $target.show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$('img').hide();` is a global lookup for all images.  You have to change your selector for each block so it targets just the images it should hide.

Comment: Fortunately the images are already separate and encapsulated in a div, each with their own unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, the same goes for the other selector `.carouselpopart`.

```
$('.carouselanimal').click(function(a){
   $.each($('.carouselanimal'),function(i,v){
     $($(v).attr("target")).hide();
   });
   $($(this).attr("target")).show();
});
```